# DataTable contains a column that doesn't exist c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I've been trying to reset a datatable so that the user can load another xml file.
Although i keep getting duplicate name exception even though the datatable doesn't have any columns attached to it.

Code snippet example,

```
string rdr = (Path.ChangeExtension(filepath, ".xsd"));
ds.ReadXmlSchema(rdr);
ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);
resetDataTable(dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns.Count);//This gives 0
foreach (DataColumn c in ds.Tables[1].Columns)//ds.Tables[1] is the sheet that the data is on, 
//it's probably due to how the xml are laid out. They're created out of a script, so they always follow the 
//same rules
{
    if(dt.Columns.Contains(c.ColumnName)){
        //It enters here even though it has no columns
        dt.Columns.Remove(c.ColumnName);
        //ArgumentException trying to delete a column that doesn't 
        //belong to the datatable
    }
    dt.Columns.Add(c.ColumnName);
    //Will crash here normaly saying the column already exists.
}
private void resetDataTable(DataTable dt){
     dt.Columns.Clear();
     dt.Clear();
}
```

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges, `dt` is a `DataTable` and `ds.Tables[1]` is probably a different one. Side-note: the first table is `ds.Tables[0]`.

Comment: instead of resetting...create a new reference?!

Comment: When loading from the xml, it puts the data on the ds.Tables[1] table and I load those to my dataTable, Normally it'd probably be on ds.Tables[0], but the inputs xml that are entered place it on the second sheet. Concerning creating a new reference, i'll retry real quick, i did that before and it caused problems later on in the with it being dereferenced.

Comment: We need to see how dt is being assigned in order to answer this.  Chances are as @TimSchmelter pointed out, it's probably a different object reference (vs. ds.Tables[1])